# OBDSim Connection with Android Device over Bluetooth on Windows 8.1

Tags: android, bluetooth, windows-8.1, obd-ii, com0com

I have worked since last day on this topic. I want to develop android application about obd-ii scanner. There are many open source project on **Github** or **Google Codes**. I have to find obd-ii simulator to  developed this application **without car or any odb-ii chip**.

I found OBDSim to create sample data and answer the requests that send by my application. I encountered many problems and solved these problems by reading many documents and blog post. But I have last one problem and I need to your helps.

New version of OBDsim support Windows for Bluetooth connection now with using **com0com**. When I install com0com, I faced signature problem and I solved this problem to disable related windows feature. I have also set incoming port of Bluetooth to COM4. Everything are good so far. After that I want to create virtual ports by using com0com. It already create one pair when install. They are CNCA0 and CNCB0. I am only trying to change second port of this pair from CNCB0 to COM4. But windows gives error about COM4 is already using. Still I completed and assign COM4 instead of CNCB0. After that I run obdsim.exe and it start to create log like this;

```
SimPort name: CNCA0  
Successfully initialised obdsim, entering main loop  
10.046624 seconds. 0 samples, 0 queries. 0.00 s/s, 0.00 q/s  
10.049810 seconds. 0 samples, 0 queries. 0.00 s/s, 0.00 q/s  
10.049377 seconds. 0 samples, 0 queries. 0.00 s/s, 0.00 q/s
```

In this duration, I started to android application and press start live data button. I give and error on android phone about Bluetooth Connection Error - read failed, socket might closed or timeout. This is one scenario.

In second scenario, I removed the break com0com and I directly connect OBDsim to COM4. And I run obdsim.exe again. It also hava same output as before scenario. After I started t android application output change like this.

```
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
10.066543 seconds. 0 samples, 6 queries. 0.00 s/s, 0.60 q/s
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
10.030909 seconds. 0 samples, 5 queries. 0.00 s/s, 0.50 q/s
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
10.034040 seconds. 0 samples, 6 queries. 0.00 s/s, 0.60 q/s
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
```

And I cant see any changes on my application.

If you know what is the problem or something that I made mistake or I forget, I am waiting or your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Okey. I solved my problem about this topic.

First of all, **com0com** is not necessary to communicate with OBDSim on Windows.
I can successfully connect to my application and OBDSim and I can see values on my android phone screen.

My problem was about OBD Reader program on Android. I didn't understand the reason of this situation but OBDSim couldn't connect to all OBD readers. I suggest you to use torque lite android application when you try connect OBDSim. And you should be careful on order of process.

- Firstly, you should make pair your computer and mobile phone. (Sometimes it is necessary to remove pair and make pair again.)
- After that you should run > **obdsim.exe -w COMx** (x is your Bluetooth income port name. You can set this port on your PC's Bluetooth settings -> Com Ports)
- Lastly you should open your application and try to connect your computer by Bluetooth.

This solution works for me. You can try other application.

Thanks,
M. Salih.

Comment: hi ,, i am lil bit confused about how to run it ....I have downloaded compressed file from **https://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/obdsim.html** after extracting it i got a obsim.exe ... but i dont know how to run it ... i double clicked on it ... but it didt worked